# Volume of a polytope with relaxed constraints

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, polytopes

Consider a polytope in $n$ dimensions defined by a set of linear constraints:

$$P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \leq b\}$$

where A is some $m \times n$ constraint matrix, and $b = (b_1,\ldots,b_m)$ is a vector of coefficients. Now suppose we *relax* each of the constraints by some $\epsilon$ to get the new polytope:

$$P' = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \leq b+\epsilon\}$$

where $b + \epsilon = (b_1 + \epsilon,\ldots,b_m + \epsilon)$.

Clearly the volume of $P'$ is larger than the volume of $P$. I want an inequality of the form:

$$Vol(P') \leq Vol(P) + f(\epsilon)$$
for some function $f$. What is the tightest bound I can get?

(Note -- I also posted this on math.stackexchange, but got no responses)

Comment: This question was [asked on Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823200/volume-of-a-polytope-with-relaxed-constraints) shortly before being posted here. Dear @Derrick G., quickly posting a question on both Math.StackExchange and MathOverflow leads to duplication of effort and is frowned upon by both communities. Please wait a few days before reposting any question. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It is not clear what do you mean by tightest bound --- in which sense tightest?
Also you did not say from above or from below. Anyway, let me say something, hope it will help.

Let
$$Q = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \leq \mathbb{1}\},$$
where $\mathbb{1}=(1,\dots,1)$
Note that 
$$P'=P+\varepsilon\cdot Q.$$

A. You can get lower bounds from [Brunn–Minkowski inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunn%E2%80%93Minkowski_inequality) in terms of volumes of $P$ and $Q$.

B. The value $\mathrm{vol} P'$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.
The coefficient in front of $\varepsilon^k$ 
is expressed through the [mixed volumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_volume) of $k$ copies of $Q$
and $n-k$ copies of $P$.